How to properly stop a python proxy server for react without blocking the terminal (main thread)
Right now, I have a proxy server that is started like so:

An endpoint is called by the user which starts the proxy server and redirects to the proxy origin URL

React
const loginURL = `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}/site-login`;
    const checkLoginStatusURL = 'http://localhost:3001/site/login';

    let siteWindow = window.open(
      loginURL,
      'Site Login',
      'width=1728,height=1117'
    );

Python
html_content = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Site Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3001/site/login'
    </script>
</body>
</html>
"""

@app.get("/site-login")
async def site_login():
    global proxy_task, shutdown_event

    print("Site login endpoint called!")

    if proxy_task is not None:
        shutdown_event.set()  # Signal the existing proxy server to stop
        await asyncio.wait([proxy_task])  # Wait for the proxy server to stop

    shutdown_event.clear()  # Reset the stop event
    proxy_task = asyncio.create_task(start_proxy_server())

    return HTMLResponse(content=html_content)

async def start_proxy_server():
    from hypercorn.asyncio import serve
    from hypercorn.config import Config
    global shutdown_event

    config = Config()
    config.bind = ["0.0.0.0:3001"]

    async def proxy_lifecycle():
        try:
            await serve(ASGIProxy(app), config)
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("Proxy server task was cancelled")
            raise

    server_task = asyncio.create_task(proxy_lifecycle())

    await shutdown_event.wait()  # Wait until the stop_event is set
    server_task.cancel()  # Cancel the server task
    try:
        await asyncio.wait([server_task])  # Ensure the task is fully cancelled
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        print(f"Proxy server stopped: {e}")
    print("Proxy server has been stopped cleanly")


The stopping of the proxy server is called conditionally by the proxy server

@app.get("/stop-proxy")
async def stop_proxy():
    global shutdown_event, proxy_task

    if shutdown_event is not None:
        shutdown_event.set()
    if proxy_task is not None:
        await proxy_task

    return {"status": "stopping proxy"}

Conditional Stopping in ASGIProxy class:
if '/feed' in str(response_headers_dict.get('location')) or (decoded_content is not False and '/nhome' in decoded_content) or response.status_code == 403:
            print(f"Login Successful! {global_cookies}")
            
            # Save Preprocessed Response cookies to global cookies
            if 'set-cookie' in response.headers:
                login_cookies = response.headers["set-cookie"]
                self.save_cookies_to_json(login_cookies)
                print(f'Final response cookies before preprocessing: {login_cookies}')
                preprocessed_cookies = self.format_cookies(login_cookies)
                print(f'Final response cookies after preprocessing: {preprocessed_cookies}')
                global_cookies = preprocessed_cookies
            
            # Stop Server
            await stop_proxy()

But for the love of god, the proxy server never stops even when stop_proxy is called, and it never stops even when I press ctrl+c. Why is this the case? How do I properly start and stop the proxy server?
